# Why does mouse movement minimize other application to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

I am experiencing something strange:

When I grab the title bar of an application's window and move it in a certain way, all other windows which are currently displayed on the desktop get minimized.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What is this, and how do I disable it? And if it's a feature: What is it for? I never found it useful. It just unnerves me a few times per day.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a windows multitasking “feature”

To disable:

Click start -> settings -> system -> multitasking

Set “title bar window shake” to off